# Why is my if-else block not running more than twice when it should?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, math

I am trying to find the multiplicative digital root MDR and multiplicative persistence MR of a given input value. For this, I have to use three functions
MDR- to find the multiplicative digital root
MPersistence - to find multiplicative persistence
prodDigits - to find the product of digits of the input number.
I have used the if-else block to give a recursive call to prodDigits function. But it only runs twice.
For example if I give input 86, It should run as 86 -> 48 -> 32 -> 6 (MDR 6, Mpersistence 3)
But my code only gives the output till 32 and persistence as 1

```
num = input("Enter the number")

def MDR(num):
    c = 0
    def prodDigits(num):

        individual_ele = map(int, str(num))
        productOfDigits = 1
        for i in individual_ele:
            productOfDigits *= i
        print(productOfDigits)
        return productOfDigits
   
    res = prodDigits(num)
    c += 1

    if res>=10:
        res1 = str(res)
        prodDigits(res1)
    else:
        print(res)
    
    print("Mpersistence is",c)


def Mpersistence():
    MDR(num)

Mpersistence()
```

The output is

```
Enter the number86
48
32
Mpersistence = 1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: please copy your code instead of using a screenshot, it makes it harder to help you (surrounded with ```)

Comment: Sorry, Is it ok now?

Comment: Hi, could you please explain in concise words what "multiplicative digital root" and "multiplicative persistence" mean?

Comment: @Stef Hi, If all digits of a number n are multiplied by each other repeating with the product, the one-digit no. obtained at last is called the Multiplicative Digital Root (MDR) For eg - 86 -> (8*6) 48 -> (4*8) 32 -> (3*2) 6. Here 6 is the MDR

The number of times digit needs to be multiplied to reach one digit is called the multiplicative persistence of n. Here we need to multiply thrice to reach at a single-digit value so the MPersistence is 3

Answer (score 0):

An `if/else` block shouldn't run "more than once". An `if/else` block runs just once.

What you are looking for is called a **loop** and can be achieved with the `while` keyword.

Compare these two functions:

```py
def run_once(num):
  if (num > 9):
    num = prodDigits(num)
  return num

def run_morethanonce(num):
  while (num > 9):
    num = prodDigits(num)
  return num

x = run_once(86)
# = 48

y = run_morethanonce(num)
# = 6
```

Note that "if" and "while" are both English words. Read the code of these two functions in English. The first one calls `prodDigits` if some condition is satisfied. The second one keeps calling `prodDigits` as long as some condition is satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for the very first statement. I had forgotten about it. Actually, I tried using a while loop in my code previously too. It entered into an infinite loop, the only statement that worked was the if-else block. I don't know how to resolve it.